# MongoDb: find(), property of document matches one value of given array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm making a search bar in my app and I'm using mongodb to fetch the results.
The situation is as following:

When the _group property (which is an ObjectId) of the post document is equal to one of the values in the exampleArray I want this post to be included in my end result. How would I do this?

```
 const exampleArray = ['ObjectId1', 'ObjectId1', 'ObjectId1'];

    const posts = await Post.find({_group: exampleArray })
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will need to use the MongoDB [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), which is used to compare a field against a list of values.

Try the following:

```
posts = await Post.find({_group: { "$in" : exampleArray } })
```